# UML Sequence Diagarams Instantiation Order

Tags: c++, uml

is there any tool I can create UML sequence diagrams putting stress on OBJECT INITIALIZATION , that in practice mean tracing each other constructor calls in their procedural workflow .... I try to get rid of singletons in some projects and having a clear graph what creates what would be very handy . What I Need is either fee UML Tool or Visual Paradigm ( as I use it's trial version ) . Ohh I would forget , what I am looking is round-triping engineering tool for C++ , not doing scratches from zero ....

Comment: I use UMLet, it's fast and cool, it's free and open source, but doesn't make your code from diagram, not pro, but contains everything

Comment: >>EXISTING CODE TO DIAGRAM<<

Comment: Hmm, to do this, I don't think there is any perfect tool available because you would just get class and sequence(maybe) diagram, but "Astah" and "Visual Paradigm" are maybe good for you